# How to use the double pointer structure correctly

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Below is the code, I'm so puzzled of how to use that double pointer int `struct  _AReport` and `struct  _BReport`.

My system is running on a Embedded computer, I use VS to debug this parts.
My system is composed of 1 `struct  _AReport`, 17 `struct  _BReport` and 16 `struct  _CReport` on the whole.

The goal is that `struct  _AReport` will contain all the informations.

I'm poor at English, thanks for being patient.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
typedef struct _AReport AReport;
typedef struct _BReport BReport;
typedef struct _CReport CReport;

typedef struct _AData AData;
typedef struct _BData BData;
typedef struct _CData CData;
typedef struct _ABCDatas ABCDatas;
struct  _AReport
{
    AData *adata;
    BReport **breport;
};

struct  _BReport
{
    int _b;
    BData *bdata;
    CReport **creport;
};

struct  _CReport
{
    int _c;
    CData *cdata;
};

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    AReport Ar;
    //BReport Br_dyadic[17][16] = { 0 };
    BReport Br[17];
    BReport *Br_Pointer = Br;
    Ar.breport = &(Br_Pointer);

    for (i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    {
        Br[i]._b = i + 1;
    }
    (Ar.breport[0])->_b = 99;
    (Ar.breport[0] + 1)->_b = 99;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What problem do you have when you run the code?

Comment: @Mawg Hi ,Mawg, The code posted didn't have any errors, i' wondering whether i did the right way.

Comment: You mean that it compiled & linked, I think. It might still have errors at run-time. Does it? When you run it, does it do what  you expect it to?

Comment: Following seems incorrect `(Ar.breport[0])->_b = 99;` since you have `breport` point to a 1D array & it is not itself an array. Instead try: `(*(Ar.breport))[0]._b = 99;` But I'm just guessing here as it is not clear what error you are seeing.

Comment: The behaviour is undefined because the program is using identifiers that start with an underscore and a capital letter. Such names are reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is *does this problem require pointers to pointers*, the answer is no: pointer arithmetics allow a single pointer to access all elements of a 1D array.

But if your question is *does the last lines correctly access the elements of `Br`*, then the answer it yes. Here is what actually happens:

- `Ar.breport` is a pointer to a pointer to the first element of array `Br` (from `BReport *Br_Pointer = Br; Ar.breport = &(Br_Pointer);`, `BrPointer` being a pointer to first element of `Br`)
- `Ar.breport[0]` is *by definition* the same as `*(Ar.breport)` => it is a pointer to the first element of `Br`
- so `Ar.breport[0] + 1` is by pointer arithmetics a pointer to the second element of `Br`

It is then legal to use those 2 pointers to dereference them and access the `_b` member of the `BReport` they point to.

You could make sure of that by simply adding:

```
printf("%d - %d - %d\n", Br[0]._b, Br[1]._b, Br[2]._b);
```

just before the `return 0;` (of after adding `#include <stdio.h>`...) and that should print `99 - 99 - 2`